# Scikit-learn (Python): what does f_regression() compute?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand what f_regression() in the feature selection package does. 
(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression)

According to the documentation, the first step in f_regression is as follows:

```
"1. the regressor of interest and the data are orthogonalized wrt constant regressors."
```

What does this line mean, exactly?  What are these constant regressors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the mean is subtracted on both variables.

A constant regressor is a vector full of ones. What this vector can explain in your data is then subtracted out. This leads to a vector with zero sum, i.e. a centered variable.

What `f1_regression` essentially calculates is correlation, a scalar product between centered and appropriately rescaled variables.

The resulting score is a function of this value and the degrees of freedom, i.e. the dimensionality of the vectors. The higher the score, the more probably the variables are associated.